# Maximum of Quadratic form

Tags: matrices, optimization, quadratic-forms

Let $M$ be a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix.  Is it true that 
$$
\max_{x \in [0,1]^n} |x^T M x| = \max_{y \in \{\pm 1\}^n} |y^T M y|?
$$
Clearly, the left hand side is greater than or equal to the right, but I'm not sure if the other inequality holds.

Comment: The statement is true if $M$ is positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $n=2$ and:
$$M=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
you have:
$$y^T M y = y_1^2-y_2^2$$
which is $0$ if $y \in \{-1,1\}^2$ but the max over $[0,1]^n$ is not $0$.